# How to handle multiple users simultaneously editing an entry?

Tags: entries, users, admin, saveentry, editor

If 2 or more people are editing a entry at the same time in Craft, the last person to save the entry overrides everyone else's work. It doesn't seem any diffing is involved to resolve this. I'm using matrix fields mostly.

WordPress handles it by locking a post while someone is editing. This is done by sending an AJAX request to the server when auto saving, updating the "last edited" date and which user is editing.

Does anyone know if a plugin exists already for Craft that implements this post locking feature? Or is there something already in Craft to avoid these conflicts?

Comment: You can workaround the problem with entry revisions. If you want to see it added, [vote](http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/9009169-add-an-alert-or-warning-when-multiple-authors-are) for it.

Comment: @RitterKnight Voted! Revisions is useful to get back lost work but still a pain because you can't rollback specific parts

Comment: I agree. Would be nice to see feature parity in this respect with WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't a native way to do this and I'm not aware of a plugin that's has the functionality.

You can semi-work around it with entry revisions, but if you think this should be a core feature you can [vote for it](http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/9009169-add-an-alert-or-warning-when-multiple-authors-are)!

Comment: Looks like I might have to make this plugin maybe